# Un/hide Specific Collection Elements

Tags: python

[image][image]Is there any way to specify the collection in which I want to show or hide the elements that are inside it ?  Is this line of code useful to do that?

`bpy.ops.outliner.collection_show_inside()`

Comment: Hello, could you share a screenshot showing what you are trying to achieve ? I'm not sure I get your problem

Comment: If I am trying to find a way to assign the action to hide and show all objects in a specific collection. The way I am currently working is unhiding all objects but when I do that in a very heavy scene it complicates things so I wanted to specify that action to only the cutters folder that is created in the BoxCutter addon.